# onkeypress event not firing in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
$(".tbSearchBox").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        alert("ye");
        searchSet = $(this).val();
        $(".btnSerachButton").click();
    }
});
```

Im using the above code to detect whether the user has typed something in a search box then hit enter instead of pressing the search button. this works for all browsers apart from IE. IE can read the on keyup event but bypasses the if statement used. Any idea why?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.which/ "The event.which property normalizes event.keyCode and event.charCode. It is recommended to watch event.which for keyboard key input."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There some incompatibility in ie regarding event and keycode so to make it browser compatible try this

```
$(".tbSearchBox").keypress(function (event) {
    var ev = event || window.event;
    var key = ev.keyCode || ev.which || ev.charCode;
    if (key == 13) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        alert("ye");
        searchSet = $(this).val();
        $(".btnSerachButton").click();
    }
});
```

Comment: tried but ie still bypasses the javascript and posts the page

Comment: can you post html element '.tbSearchBox'?

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` maybe?

Comment: tried adding this as the first line, didnt make any difference, page still got posted before javascript

Comment: try keypress instead keyup.. updated the answer.. check if that helps you

Comment: good idea. weirdly though on keypress stops it working in other browsers which i dont get.

Comment: WHAYYYY WORKING! i tried adding onkeypress just to my code but when i copied and pasted yours all worked good man! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var code = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
```

or maybe even

```
var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
```

Comment: The `event.which` property normalizes `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`. It should therefore be enough to just watch `event.which`. See http://api.jquery.com/event.which/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.charCode#Notes

Comment: thanks, gave this a go but no luck, page just gets posted before reading the line

Answer (score 0):

You should [use `event.which` here](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) to normalise `event.keyCode` and `event.charCode`:

```
if (event.which == 13) ...
```

Comment: tried this, still works for other browsers but not ie. ie posts the page before the javascript